# Div next to div no use of float

Tags: html, css

I want two divs next to each other. I already tried `floating` but it did not work.

I have foundation but use my own CSS most of the time

```css
.mijn_producten{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    margin-left: 60%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: white;

}
.contact_gev{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: white;
}
.contact_gev h1{
    margin-left: 5%;
}
.contact_gev p{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 10%
}
.background_content{
    background: #f9f9f9;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sapphire webshop</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" media="all"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/csszelf.css" media="all"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        /*<?php include 'header.php';?>*/
        <div class = "background_content">
            <div class= "contact_gev">
                <h1>Contact gegevens</h1> 
                <form>
                    <p>Gebruikersnaam: <input class="registreren" type="text" name="Gebruikersnaam"></p>
                    <p>Voornaam: <input class="registreren" type="text" name="voornaam"></p>
                    <p>Achternaam: <input class="registreren" type="text" name="achternaam"></p>
                    <p>Telefoonnummer: <input class="registreren" type="text" name="telefoonnummer"></p>
                    <p>Geboorte datum: <input class="registreren" type="text" name="geboortedatum"></p>
                    <p>Adres:<input class="registreren" type="text" name="adres"></p>    
                    <p>Postcode:<input class="registreren" type="text" name="postcode"></p>
                    <p>plaats:<input class="registreren" type="text" name="plaats"></p>
                    <p>land:<input class="registreren" type="text" name="land"></p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class ="mijn_producten">
                <h1> Mijn producten</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        /* <?php include 'footer.php';?> */
    </body>
</html>
```

here you can see my code i already used float left right and all the position variants

Comment: remove left right margin from bot side add float left on both element and then give width for example 50%

Comment: You could also use `display: inline-block` and remove the margins. Or you could take a look at flexbox.

Comment: @IsmailFarooq thanks that works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove left right margin from bot side add float left on both element and then give width for example 50%.

HTML

```
<div class="background_content">
  <div class="contact_gev">
    <h1>Contact gegevens</h1>
    <form>
      <p>Gebruikersnaam:
        <input class="registreren" type="text" name="Gebruikersnaam">
      </p>
      <p>Voornaam:
        <input class="registreren" type="text" name="voornaam">
      </p>
      <p>Achternaam:
        <input class="registreren" type="text" name="achternaam">
      </p>
      <p>Telefoonnummer:
        <input class="registreren" type="text" name="telefoonnummer">
      </p>
      <p>Geboorte datum:
        <input class="registreren" type="text" name="geboortedatum">
      </p>
      <p>Adres:
        <input class="registreren" type="text" name="adres">
      </p>
      <p>Postcode:
        <input class="registreren" type="text" name="postcode">
      </p>
      <p>plaats:
        <input class="registreren" type="text" name="plaats">
      </p>
      <p>land:
        <input class="registreren" type="text" name="land">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="mijn_producten">
    <h1> Mijn producten</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mijn_producten {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #dddddd;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact_gev {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #dddddd;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact_gev h1 {
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.contact_gev p {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 10%
}

.background_content {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbwwcufs/)